# How to find the smallest number(s) in a list of elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

Here is my program,

```
item_no = []
minimum = 1000
for i in range(5):
    input_no = int(input("Enter an item number: "))
    item_no.append(input_no)
for i in item_no:
    if i < minimum:
       minimum = i
small = item_no.index(minimum)
print (item_no[small])
```

Example input: `[5, 3, 3, 8, 9]`

Example output: `3`

How can I change my program to output the possibility of two or more same smallest numbers in an array?

Example input: `[2, 2, 2, 6, 5, 8, 9]`

Expected output: `[2, 2, 2]`

The program should be written as simple as possible using very few inbuilt functions in Python 2.7/3.

Comment: *"same smallest numbers in an array?"* For lists having no duplicates, what do you expect to output?

Comment: Just the smallest number (unique, of course).

Comment: @us asking ppl to upvote is done by improving your question so that the mayority of users things its worthy and upvotes - not by asking for votes in comments - thats plain rude and probably wll get you downvotes. BEtter would have been:  `I edited my question to make it more clear, can you please take a look at it?`

Comment: You can start by renaming `min` - that is the name of a built in you are shadowing by  using its name for your minimal_value. Then maybe format code as code (your expected input/output) and then give it time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the `min()` built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
item_no = [3,5,7,3,5,7,3,5,7,9]

min_val = min(item_no)    # what is the minimal value?

# print item with position
for i,v in enumerate(item_no):
    if v==min_val:
        print(f"{min_val} at position {i}")

# get all min values
all_mins = [i for i in item_no if i==min_val] 
print( all_mins )
```

Output:

```
3 at position 0
3 at position 3
3 at position 6
[3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already got a loop that finds the lowest value, using a *less than* test.  You could extend that to consider what happens when you find a value that's *equal to* the previous smallest value.

Also, what happens if your inputs are large, e.g. [1500, 2000, 1800]?

Comment: Possibly I could increase the value of min to larger value such as 10000? But only if the program requires such inputs. Otherwise, this specific program is supposed to use just single digit values.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation. Filter out what is needed from list:

```
item_no = [3,5,7,3,5,7,3,5,7,9]

min_value = min(item_no)
print(list(filter(lambda x: x == min_value, item_no)))

# [3, 3, 3]
```